# What did Bronn do to the thieves?

Tags: game-of-thrones

> Lord Varys enters and greets them both. Varys unctuously compliments
>   Bronn on the Gold Cloaks performance, explaining to Tyrion that they
>   have reduced the rate of theft in the city. Tyrion wonders how Bronn
>   accomplished the improvement. Bronn admits that they rounded up all of
>   the known thieves. Tyrion asks if they were questioned and Bronn
>   declines to say more, adding that they need only worry about the
>   unknown thieves from now on. Tyrion says that they spoke about such
>   brutal methods and Bronn agrees that they did. Bronn then questions if
>   they have ever been in a city under siege. They do not answer and
>   Bronn suggests that he knows something that might not be in the books.
>   He elucidates that starvation is the great killer of a siege and that
>   food becomes the most valuable commodity during a siege. He says that
>   if things are bad enough the poor will turn to cannibalism while the
>   rich will give away their most valued possessions in exchange for
>   simple provisions. He says that the thieves prosper most in a siege.
>   Varys agrees that extreme measures are warranted under the
>   circumstances.[8]

http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Bronn_Season_2

Did he kill them all?

Comment: The bowls of 'Brown' in Flea Bottom were unusually meaty that week.

Answer (score 12):

Bronn's exact words in the show are

> - Me and the lads rounded up all the known thieves.
> - For questioning?
> - Aaaah, no.

The final fate of these thieves is not spelled out. However, considering that:

- It is unlikely that thieves that did not resist arrest would have been killed outright, because doing so would have been likely to provoke further disorder in the streets - however, anyone who resisted arrest would probably have been fine to kill or hurt;
- It is also unlikely that there would be enough food for all the thieves if they were imprisoned;
- I would certainly not put it past Bronn to let any number of thieves die in prison, dig their own grave out of town at night, or drive them in an alleyway to kill them without witnesses;
- Or, even simpler, the thieves were imprisoned and then summarily executed;

So, while the fate of the thieves is never spelled out, given the circumstances, it is not far-fetched to think that they would have been killed in various, unelaborated ways.

Comment: IIRC, in the books Bronn made a passing reference to pot shops. And Tyrion thought to himself about a bowl of brown, and made a mental note to ask Bronn which pot shops to avoid.

Comment: @sjl: I seem to remember that that reference was made for a singer that threatened Shae's cover. Also, remember that in the book, it is Jacelyn Bywater that is leader of the City Watch, so the situation would not play in the same way. (While Bronn commands several hundreds sellswords in the book, they would certainly not be executing the task of rounding up the thieves)

Comment: @sjl, actually, the pot shop reference is about Symon Silver Tongue, when Bronn is asked to kill him. He says he knows a pot shop that does a bowl of brown and Tyrion says Bronn should remind him never to eat there...

Comment: I agree with this answer. It's never said explicitly, but any truth that sees the known thieves alive does not fit the character of Bronn. He wasn'r offered anything for the thieves, yet they were his problem to take care of.